# HTML textarea element not showing initial value if name attribute is present

Tags: html, backbone.js, textarea, handlebars.js

I'm using backbone.js and handlebars.js to render a backbone view within an SPA.  My handlebars template looks like this (simplified):

```
{{#if text}}
    <textarea name="{{field}}">{{text}}</textarea>
{{/if}}
```

Rendering the template with context:

```
{ field: 'quote', text: "Your lack of faith disturbs me." }
```

yields the following valid HTML:

```
<textarea name="quote">Your lack of faith disturbs me.</textarea>
```

Unfortunately, the initial text is not visible (tested in latest Chrome and Safari), even though chrome tools shows that the initial value has been properly added to the DOM (*not* using a value attribute!).

If I remove the 'name' attribute from the template, or replace the name attribute with some other attribute (such as namex="{{field}}"), then the initial value is correctly displayed.

I've tried removing css rules one at a time to see if one of them was causing the text to be hidden, but no luck.

Also, as an experiment, I used jquery on the textarea element (after rendering was completed) to assign a value, but this value also will not show up unless I remove the name attribute.

My gut says that neither backbone nor handlebars is to blame, given that the markup is correct, but I'm out of threads to pull on with this one.

Help me, Stack Overflow, you're my only hope...

Comment: In order to help you, stackoverflow needs to see the code that creates the problem, or better a minimal demo.please read [ask]

Comment: Here's a demo showing that what you provided works http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/j1dbfzxw/

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be a synapse misfire on my part; I hadn't dug into backbone-modelbinder, a backbone.js add-on that automatically populates form fields.  The binder was resetting the value, although apparently it wasn't actually overwriting the value in the DOM (as seen in chrome tools).  That last part tripped me up: seeing the initial value in chrome tools but not on screen led me to look for much more complex solutions (and eventually to ask the SO question, thinking I had unearthed some kind of obscure bug)...

Thanks SO...